# Use `getQueueUrl` to generate sqsUrl using sqsName and awsAccountId or simply hardcode the sqsUrl string. What is the recommendation?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

Let’s say we want to send the message to SQS (from Lambda/any service.)

With the help of `sqsUrl` and the `message`  , SQS client can send the message to the SQS corresponding to `sqsUrl`.

```
// A simple SQS messaging code: 

SendMessageRequest messageRequest = new SendMessageRequest().withMessageBody(message).withQueueUrl(sqsUrl);

this.sqsClient.sendMessage(messageRequest);
```

Now there are two ways to get the `sqsUrl`:

**A. We can simply hardcode the static url string in the code.**

Pros:

a. No API call, hence less latency.

b. Simple to write and less line of code. Will have to define just the `sqsUrl` for each sqs in Configuration.

c. Many services in Amazon use this only, probably to save latency.

Cons:

a. If AWS changes the url structure in future, then the code will break. And we have to go change the url in code. But slim chance of happening this. They will make sure of compatibility.

b. Kind of hardcoding, not a good coding practice. (My opinion)

**B. Other way is to **programatically** create the `sqsUrl` using `getQueueUrl` api, which accepts `sqsName` and `awsAccountId` (optional, only required if sqs’s account is different than caller’s account.)**

Pros:

a. If we want to send the message to some random team’s sqs, but they didn’t provide the `sqsUrl`. They just provided the name of sqs and account id. In that case, generating url programatically can help.

b. If AWS changes the url structure in future, the code will require no changes, and things will work as it is.

c.There must be some reason why SQS provided getQueueUrl api, to avoid directly using url/arn. (*Yet to find any documentation where AWS recommends using this.* )

Cons:

a. Extra dependency on an api `getQueueUrl`, extra latency of ~200 ms. But should not be a concern when this much latency doesn’t matter. For ex: Offline systems, Postprocessing scenario, etc.

b. More line of codes. Will have to define `sqsName` and `accountId` for each sqs in Configuration.

Comment: A third way is that you externalize your configuration. AWS Lambda allows you to configure environment variables, which you can then read from your code. With an IaC (infrastructure as code) tool, you can create both queue and lambda, and link them together.